# Intellij editor using \r\n as line break. How to set it using \n only?

Tags: intellij-idea

I didn't find a setting for this. Source code is fine. But for some shell, \r\n will not work.

Comment: this might help http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/10/better-line-endings-managing-in-intellij-idea-12/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Default separator can be changed in the code style settings:

[image: line separator]

For the existing files you can switch it via the status bar:

[image: status bar line separator]

Answer (score 10):

#### **IntelliJ IDEA 14** & **16**:

- Change separator for IDE: `File > Settings... > Editor > Code Style > Line separator (for new files):`

  [image]
- Change separator for the current file: `File > Line Separators`

  [image]

  or from the bottom right side (`click on CRLF/LF/CR`):

  [image]